# Postfix sendmail -f configuration

Tags: postfix, sendmail, mail-forwarding, satellite, smarthost

I have Postfix installed on two servers. One of them writes e-mail (satellite) and the other one delivers the e-mails (smarthost). When I write e-mail from the satellite server I'm using the sendmail command.

My problem is that when e-mail arrives the Return-Path is set to the user@hostname where user is the user that is running sendmail and hostname is the servers hostname. If I use the parameter -f with sendmail I change that, but I'm hoping there is a way to do it in a configuration file for Postfix. Is this possible or should I just deal with having to configure all my software to add the -f argument?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using the -f parameter as much as I didn't want to. If anyone else finds a different solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.postfix.org/basic.html#myorigin

Comment: Not effecting the Return-Path. I think I'm going to end up using the -f parameter.